# Gif animation with tkinter and classes in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, gif, vlc

I'm having some problems making my gif work in this code.
its a kind of media player with a graphic equalizer :)
I'm trying to make gif play inside the "pantalla" label. I'm having an attribute error with the frame variable. I've been looking around but cannot solve the problem.
sorry for my mistakes I'm a newbie.
any help will be appreciated.

here the code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from vlc import Instance
import time


app = Tk()
app.title("JlMultimedia")
app.iconbitmap("C:/Users/Thunder/Documents/Projects/Python/auricular.ico")
app.geometry("340x250")
app.config(bg="blue")

frames = [PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/Thunder/Documents/Projects/Python/imagenes/equalizer1.gif', format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(5)]

def update(self, ind):
    self.frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    print(ind)
    if ind>4: #With this condition it will play gif infinitely
        ind = 0
    app.after(100, update, ind)

class Jlmultimedia:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Player = Instance('--loop')
        

        capa = Frame(app)
        capa.config(bg="#ffffff")
        capa.pack(expand="1")


        capa1 = Frame(capa, bg="#0000ff")
        capa1.config()
        capa1.pack(expand="1")

       
        pantalla = Label(capa1, image=self.frame)
        pantalla.grid(row="0", columnspan="3")
        

        self.playimage = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Thunder/Documents/Projects/Python/imagenes/play4.png")
        self.stopimage = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Thunder/Documents/Projects/Python/imagenes/stop4.png")
        self.pauseimage = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Thunder/Documents/Projects/Python/imagenes/pause4.png")
        self.nextimage = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Thunder/Documents/Projects/Python/imagenes/forw4.png")
        self.backimage = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Thunder/Documents/Projects/Python/imagenes/rew4.png")

        capa2 = LabelFrame(capa)
        capa2.config(bg="#ffffff")
        capa2.pack(expand="1")

        playboton = Button(capa2, image=self.playimage, bd="0", command=self.play)
        playboton.grid(row="1", column="1")

        self.volVar = IntVar()
        volboton = Scale(capa2, from_=100, to=0, resolution=1, length=90, 
        label="Vol", variable=self.volVar, command=self.set_volume)
        volboton.grid(row="1", column="6")
                     
        stopboton = Button(capa2, image=self.stopimage, bd="0", command=self.stop)
        stopboton.grid(row="1", column="2")

        pauseboton = Button(capa2, image=self.pauseimage, bd="0", command=self.pause)
        pauseboton.grid(row="1", column="4")

        nextboton = Button(capa2, image=self.nextimage, bd="0", command=self.next)
        nextboton.grid(row="1", column="3")

        preboton = Button(capa2, image=self.backimage, bd="0", command=self.previous)
        preboton.grid(row="1", column="5")

        # panel to hold player time slider
        self.timeVar = DoubleVar()
        self.timeSliderLast = 0
        self.timeSlider = Scale(capa1, variable=self.timeVar, command=self.OnTime, 
                                       from_=0, to=1000, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=328, showvalue=0)  # label='Time',
        #self.timeSlider.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X, expand=1)
        self.timeSliderUpdate = time.time()
        self.timeSlider.grid(row="1", columnspan="5")

    def addPlaylist(self):
        self.mediaList = self.Player.media_list_new()
        path = r"C:/Users/Thunder/Documents/Projects/Python/musica"
        songs = os.listdir(path)
        for s in songs:
            self.mediaList.add_media(self.Player.media_new(os.path.join(path,s)))
        self.listPlayer = self.Player.media_list_player_new()
        self.listPlayer.set_media_list(self.mediaList)

    def set_volume(self, *unuse):
        vol = min(self.volVar.get(), 100)
        self.listPlayer.get_media_player().audio_set_volume(vol)

    def play(self):
        self.listPlayer.play()
    def next(self):
        self.listPlayer.next()
    def pause(self):
        self.listPlayer.pause()
    def previous(self):
        self.listPlayer.previous()
    def stop(self):
        self.listPlayer.stop()

    def OnTime(self, *unused):
        if self.listPlayer:
            t = self.timeVar.get()
            if self.timeSliderLast != int(t):
                self.listPlayer.get_media_player().set_time(int(t * 1e3))  # milliseconds
                self.timeSliderUpdate = time.time()

myPlayer = Jlmultimedia()
myPlayer.addPlaylist()


app = mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include the error in your question.

Comment: First you didn't call `update()` function.  Second you need to update the `image` option of label `pantalla` inside `update()` as well because updating `self.frame` will not update the label.  Final `self.frame` is undefined and `pantalla` is a local variable which cannot be accessed inside `update()` function.

Comment: Sorry, Bryan, it's my first post I forgot to include the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- `update()` has never been executed
- `image` option of label `pantalla` should be update as well inside `update()`
- `pantalla` is a local variable inside `Jlmultimedia.__init__()`, you should make it instance variable `self.pantalla`
- `self.frame` is undefined
- `app = mainloop()` should be `app.mainloop()`

Below is a modified `update()`:

```
def update(ind=0):
    myPlayer.pantalla.config(image=frames[ind%len(frames)])
    app.after(100, update, ind+1)
```

And changing `pantalla` to instance variable inside `__init__()`:

```
class Jlmultimedia:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.pantalla = Label(capa1)
        self.pantalla(row=0, columnspan=3)
        ...
```

Then call `update()` before `app.mainloop()`:

```
...
update()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: acc1668 you are the best man!!. thank you. problem solved.