# How do I create a gif that is animated in tkinter python canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, gif

I am trying to create place a gif onto my tkinter canvas, however it is just a still image when it is placed.
Does anyone know how I could maybe place it but it moves when the code runs?

Comment: Have you ever tried to search stackoverflow on "tkinter gif animation"?

Comment: please take a look at this answer : [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236877/15919783

Comment: Yes @acw1668 I did but they weren't animated

Comment: I can find [play-an-animated-gif-in-python-with-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770847/play-an-animated-gif-in-python-with-tkinter) and [gif-animation-with-tkinter-and-classes-in-python-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063321/gif-animation-with-tkinter-and-classes-in-python-3).