# How to fix the frame by frame animation if it keep shows previous image while the image is changing to a next image frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a program that switches frame by frame animation when the button for each is pressed uning tkinter. In order to build the animation, I need a delay between every image changes of animation. So I tried using time.sleep, threading.Timer, and schedule, but time.sleep didn't work because it stops the whole code, threading.Timer didn't work because when animations are switched they keep changes the image frame until whole animation function is done, and schedule didn't work because its funtion wasn't fit to build frame by frame animation. Which other codes I can try? If it can work when some codes are changed, how should I fix them? Here's my whole code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os
import time
import threading

#Variable
x = int

#function
def start():
    anim1_1_L.place(x=0, y=0)
    anim1_1_B.place(x=100, y=0)
    anim2_1_B.place(x=100, y=30)
    anim1_1_B.config(text="taco", command=lambda:[taco()])
    anim2_1_B.config(text="tree", command=lambda:[tree()])
    main()

def main():
    global x
    if x == 1:
        animation_1()
    else:
        animation_2()

def animation_1():
    threading.Timer(0.0, animation_1_S2).start()
    threading.Timer(0.5, animation_1_S1).start()
    threading.Timer(1.0, animation_1_S2).start()
    threading.Timer(1.5, animation_1_S1).start()
    threading.Timer(2.0, main).start()

def animation_2():
    threading.Timer(0.0, animation_2_S1).start()
    threading.Timer(0.5, animation_2_S2).start()
    threading.Timer(1.0, animation_2_S3).start()
    threading.Timer(1.5, animation_2_S4).start()
    threading.Timer(2.0, animation_2_S5).start()
    threading.Timer(2.5, animation_2_S6).start()
    threading.Timer(3.0, animation_2_S7).start()
    threading.Timer(3.5, main).start()

def taco():
    global x
    x = 1
    main()

def tree():
    global x
    x = 2
    main()

#animation1_slide
def animation_1_S1():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=anim1_1)

def animation_1_S2():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=anim1_2)

#animation2_slide
def animation_2_S1():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=tr_1)

def animation_2_S2():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=tr_2)

def animation_2_S3():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=tr_3)

def animation_2_S4():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=tr_4)

def animation_2_S5():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=tr_5)

def animation_2_S6():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=tr_6)

def animation_2_S7():
    anim1_1_L.config(image=tr_7)

#File_location
print (os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) )

#Windowm
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("796x448")
window.resizable(0,0)

#Load_Images
anim1_1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/1.png")
anim1_2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/2.png")
tr_1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/tree1.gif")
tr_2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/tree2.gif")
tr_3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/tree3.gif")
tr_4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/tree4.gif")
tr_5 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/tree5.gif")
tr_6 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/tree6.gif")
tr_7 = tk.PhotoImage(file="image/tree7.gif")

#Widgets_setup
anim1_1_L = tk.Label(window, image=anim1_1, width=100, height=100)
anim1_1_B = tk.Button(window, font=("Calbri", 10))
anim2_1_B = tk.Button(window, font=("Calbri", 10))

#Window_mainloop
start()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to animate in tkinter is to use `window.after(time,function)` .For example : let's suppose that we want to create a animation program so :

```
animation_platform = window.Canvas(width = 120,height = 120)
frames = [frame_1,frame_2,frame_3]
number_of_frames = len(frames)
delay_between_frames = 1000 #in millisecondes 
frame = 0
animation_platform.create_image(0,0,image = frames(frame),tag = 'template')

def animation():
     global frame
     if frame <= number_of frames-1 :
            frame+=1
            animation_platform.itemconfigure('template',image = frames[frame])
            window.after(delay_between_frames,animation)

window.after(delay_between_frames,animation)
```

**Note:** `frames` correspond to the frames of your animation ,each frame should be assign as a `PhotoImage` .For better performance you could make a `button` that start the animation .